# Expo CLI issue on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, expo

I have downloaded expo cli on ubuntu 20.04 in my root directory but I am unable to download it globally!
I want expo cli to be there globally since it's not recommended to open code editor through root directory.

This is what my terminal shows!

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/yarn'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/yarn']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/yarn'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!      path: '../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js',
npm ERR!      dest: '/usr/local/bin/yarn' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink \'../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js\' -> \'/usr/local/bin/yarn\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/yarn' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ritik/.npm/_logs/2020-07-03T19_44_34_737Z-debug.log
```

Comment: did you tried to install expo-cli by running this command : `npm install -g expo-cli` ?

Comment: Yeah , I did it through that only and got the error message stated above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a permissions issue. you can use `sudo` to fix this but as a general recommendation never run `npm install` with `sudo` because it is a bad idea in general ,you can read more about this [here](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92)

So To minimize this issue you can configure npm to use a different directory for global packages installations as mentioned in [npm docs here](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory)

1. On the command line, In your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.npm-global
   ```
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   ```
   npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
   ```
3. In your preferred text editor, open or create a `~/.profile`  file and add this line:

   ```
   export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
   ```
4. On the command line, update your system variables:

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```
5. Finnaly try to install expo-cli globally :

   ```
   npm install -g expo-cli
   ```

**Or if** you want a quick fix you can try this

1. open a terminal and run :

   ```
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
   ```
2. try to install expo-cli ,  run :

   ```
    npm i -g expo-cli
   ```

**Also** consider to avoid globall installs and use `npx` when possible read more [here](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b)

Comment: Thanks,it worked!
On another side note could you please suggest some resources to understand all this stuff (specifically the linux part)

Comment: OK you can start by learning Linux, there is some awesome resources all over the internet but for instance you can start with YouTube this is a good tutorial  playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bju_FdCo42w&list=PLtK75qxsQaMLZSo7KL-PmiRarU7hrpnwK , and for node js and coding in general start with YouTube as well , also search for books, i will comment later on with a github repo with some good books . another resource is https://www.codecademy.com/ , also https://www.freecodecamp.org/ , https://www.udacity.com/ , https://www.udemy.com/ and more

Comment: for Ubuntu take a look here : https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/35f3a5f8-ubuntu-server-guide.pdf  .

Comment: Also as a reminder since the answer was correct and it worked for you, can you please mark it as **Accepted** and **Upvote it** .